C++ Is there any two function which don't gives same assembly code when compiled with -O3 one with pointer and other one with reference paramaters
I wanted to understand references better so I played with some C++ code to see diffrence between references and pointers, when they compiled to assembly (-O3) I realized they both give the same assembly code.
I am curious about is there any function which gives diffrent assembly code when we use references instead of pointers as parameter.
Its more easy to understand with example: (I used godbolt to see assembly outputs.)
struct someStruct
{
    int a;
    int* ptr;
    someStruct* next;
};

int f1(someStruct* v)
{
    v->a = v->next->a + *v->next->ptr;
    v->ptr = v->next->ptr;
    v->next = v;
    return v->a;
}

int f1(someStruct& v)
{
    v.a = v.next->a + *v.next->ptr;
    v.ptr = v.next->ptr;
    v.next = &v;
    return v.a;
}

This two functions both give this same Assembly x86 code:
f1(someS*):                           # @f1(someS*)
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 16]
        mov     rdx, qword ptr [rcx + 8]
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdx]
        add     eax, dword ptr [rcx]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], rdx
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rdi
        ret


if (!v) panic(); will generated a test.  if (!&v) panic(); will be optimized out.

A reference parameter's address would be passed to the function, which is the same as passing a pointer. I'd be surprised if you saw a different between those two functions at the assembly level.

I'm guessing all the differences between references and pointers are handled by the compiler, so what's left is just pointers. Unless, of course, you count something like "taking the address of" -- but that gives semantically different results, so it's bound to be different on the assembly level

I would be inclined to say that you are looking at this the wrong way. References are a high-level concept — part of the C++ language. Whether a reference is a pointer or not underneath depends entirely on stuff that we shouldn’t need to worry about. Unless you can profile a reason not to, trust your compiler to do the Right Thing™.

bool f(int& x) { return &x != nullptr; }
bool g(int* x) { return x != nullptr; }

The first function must always return true because a reference must always be bound to an object. A pointer to an object (formed with &x) has never a null pointer value.
A pointer variable on the other hand can have a null pointer value as well and so g may or may not return true.
Compilers (probably at any non-zero optimization level) are aware of this difference between references and pointers and therefore will optimize f to return true independent of the argument, while g will contain an actual test of the condition.

Another difference with nullptr checks: Casting may change the offset from the start of the object. Casting may not change the value of a nullptr. This requires a check when dealing with pointers but not when dealing with references:
struct Foo {
  int f;
};
struct Bar: Foo {
  int b;
  virtual ~Bar() = default;
};

Foo& cast_reference(Bar& b) {
  return b;
}
Foo* cast_ptr(Bar* b) {
  return b;
}

Compiled with GCC-14 -O3:
cast_reference(Bar&):
        lea     rax, [rdi+8]
        ret
cast_ptr(Bar*):
        xor     edx, edx
        lea     rax, [rdi+8]
        test    rdi, rdi
        cmove   rax, rdx
        ret

The reason why this doesn't matter too often is that ptr->attr or ptr->method() are undefined behavior if ptr == nullptr. The compiler can eliminate the nullptr checks if the code path includes behavior that would be UB if the pointer was nullptr.
Foo& cast_add(Bar& b) {
  b.b += 1;
  return b;
}
Foo* cast_add(Bar* b) {
  b->b += 1;
  return b;
}

cast_add(Bar&):
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi+12], 1
        lea     rax, [rdi+8]
        ret
cast_add(Bar*):
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi+12], 1
        lea     rax, [rdi+8]
        ret

The UB in method calls to nullptrs also leads to a distinctive difference towards free-standing functions accepting pointers.
struct Foo {
  int f;
  void method();
};
struct Bar: Foo {
  int b;
  virtual ~Bar() = default;
};

void function(Foo*);
void function(Foo&);

void call_method(Bar& b) {
  b.method();
}
void call_method(Bar* b) {
  b->method();
}
void call_function(Bar& b) {
  function(b);
}
void call_function(Bar* b) {
  function(b);
}

call_method(Bar&):
        add     rdi, 8
        jmp     Foo::method()
call_method(Bar*):
        add     rdi, 8
        jmp     Foo::method()
call_function(Bar&):
        add     rdi, 8
        jmp     function(Foo&)
call_function(Bar*):
        lea     rax, [rdi+8]
        test    rdi, rdi
        cmovne  rdi, rax
        jmp     function(Foo*)

